# Have body of all mat-horizontal-stepper steps outside of the mat-horizontal-stepper tag

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

I want to use this : https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

but for the purposes of layout (which can be dynamic) where I may or may not have elements come in between the clickable title of a step and it's content, I want to have the content of the stepper (everything below the circular icon and the Label of the step) be outside of the DOM tag `</mat-horizontal-stepper>`.

Some other components accomplish this by naming a certain variable within the step's tag with the template name have it declared like so, later in the DOM.

If I do this, however :

```
  <div>
    <mat-horizontal-stepper labelPosition="bottom" #stepper class="width">
      <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Prerequisite Check</ng-template>
        <div [ngTemplateOutlet]="first_step"></div>
      </mat-step>
      <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Check Account Readiness</ng-template>
        <div [ngTemplateOutlet]="second_step"></div>
      </mat-step>
      <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Open</ng-template>
        <div [ngTemplateOutlet]="third_step"></div>
      </mat-step>
      <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Migration</ng-template>
        <div [ngTemplateOutlet]="fourth_step"></div>
      </mat-step>
      <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Deletion Now</ng-template>
        <div [ngTemplateOutlet]="fith_step"></div>
      </mat-step>
    </mat-horizontal-stepper>
  </div>

  <div class="card shadow margin-top controlled-height">
    <ng-template #first_step>
      <div>first_step</div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #second_step>
      <div>second_step</div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #third_step>
      <div>third_step</div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #fourth_step>
      <div>fourth_step</div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #fith_step>
      <div>fith_step</div>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
```

The content shows up but inside the first div that contains the stepper, not the card.

my second attempt went as follows (I inverted the caller and the called) :

```
  <div>
    <mat-horizontal-stepper labelPosition="bottom" #stepper class="width">
      <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Prerequisite Check</ng-template>
        <ng-template #first_step>
          <div>first_step</div>
        </ng-template>
      </mat-step>
      <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Check Account Readiness</ng-template>
        <ng-template #second_step>
          <div>second_step</div>
        </ng-template>
      </mat-step>
      <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Open</ng-template>
        <ng-template #third_step>
          <div>third_step</div>
        </ng-template>
      </mat-step>
      <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Migration</ng-template>
        <ng-template #fourth_step>
          <div>fourth_step</div>
        </ng-template>
      </mat-step>
      <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Deletion Now</ng-template>
        <ng-template #fith_step>
          <div>fith_step</div>
        </ng-template>
      </mat-step>
    </mat-horizontal-stepper>
  </div>

  <div class="card shadow margin-top controlled-height">
    <div [ngTemplateOutlet]="first_step"></div>
    <div [ngTemplateOutlet]="second_step"></div>
    <div [ngTemplateOutlet]="third_step"></div>
    <div [ngTemplateOutlet]="fourth_step"></div>
    <div [ngTemplateOutlet]="fith_step"></div>
  </div>
```

this time the content showed up where I intended it to but all were visible at the same time.

is separating title and content in matstepper possible for the material stepper?

To sum it up : I want to have the content inside `<mat-step>` outside of `</mat-horizontal-stepper>` (except `matStepLabel`, I don't care where that must go).

Answer (score 0):

I concluded that using mat-stepper wasn't worth the effort.

I reconstructed a stepper from scratch it was easy. there wasn't any feature mat stepper adds that I really lacked.

now I have the functionality I want. (separated body and clickable header)